# networkx - draw_networkx_edges shows no edge

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, networkx

## Question

Please help understand why no edge shows up with [draw_networkx_edges](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges.html) method.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

edges = [
    ("sushi/0", "sushi/0", 0.7),
    ("sushi/0", "goes/1", 0.3), 
    ("sushi/0", "with/2", 0.1), 
    ("sushi/0", "wasabi/3", 0.6), 
    ("goes/1", "sushi/0", 0.1),
    ("goes/1", "goes/1", 0.75),
    ("goes/1", "with/2", 0.75),
    ("goes/1", "wasabi/3", 0.75),
    ("with/2", "sushi/0", 0.1),
    ("with/2", "goes/1", 0.75),
    ("with/2", "with/2", 0.75),
    ("with/2", "wasabi/3", 0.75),
    ("wasabi/3", "sushi/0", 0.1),
    ("wasabi/3", "goes/1", 0.75),
    ("wasabi/3", "with/2", 0.75),
    ("wasabi/3", "wasabi/3", 0.75),
]

DG = nx.DiGraph()
DG.add_weighted_edges_from(edges)

list(nx.selfloop_edges(DG, data=True))
-----
[('sushi/0', 'sushi/0', {'weight': 0.7}),
 ('goes/1', 'goes/1', {'weight': 0.75}),
 ('with/2', 'with/2', {'weight': 0.75}),
 ('wasabi/3', 'wasabi/3', {'weight': 0.75})]
```

```
# DG.graph['edge'] = {'arrowsize': '0.6', 'splines': 'curved'}
pos = nx.spring_layout(DG)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(
    DG, 
    node_size=2000,
    node_color="cyan",
    pos=pos
)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(
    DG,
    pos=pos
)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(
    DG, 
    edgelist=list(nx.selfloop_edges(DG, data=True)),
    edge_color="r",
    connectionstyle='arc3, rad = 0.1',
    pos=pos
)
```

### Result

No edge shows up.

[image]

Comment: Probably need to use the `ax=` parameter to draw everything on the same axes (see the last example in [docs](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges.html))

Comment: @AlexK, thanks. No difference unfortunately.

Comment: I just reduced `node_size` to 200 in your example above and saw the selfloop edges graphed. You have `edgelist=list(nx.selfloop_edges(DG, data=True))` set, so the other edges are currently not graphed. You can comment that line out to see all `DG` edges.